# System Invalid Cast Exception when returning Scope Identity

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014-express

I have the following stored Procedure designed to create a new Purchase Order Header and return to me the newly created Identity for that New header:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateNewPurchaseOrderHeader @purchaseOrderNumber NCHAR(10),
@supplierId INTEGER,
@supplierInvoiceAddressId INTEGER

AS

BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON

  INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderHeaders (PurchaseOrderNumber, PurchaseOrderDate, SupplierId, SupplierInvoiceAddressId, Posted, ModifiedDate)
    VALUES (@purchaseOrderNumber, GETDATE(), @supplierId, @supplierInvoiceAddressId, 0, GETDATE());

  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END

GO
```

This is called from the following line of code (shortened somewhat for inclusion here) in my application:

```
   Dim retval As Int32 = 0
retval = CInt(ftpe.CreateNewPurchaseOrderHeader(PurOrdNum, OwnerId, InvoiceAddressId))
```

When run though The application fails at this line with the following message:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

It is worth noting that by now the Purchase Order Header has been created on the database, and I'm assuming that something is coming back (certainly if I execute the procedure directly on the database in ssms I get the new identity returned to the results pane.

I'd welcome any suggestions as to the cause of this.  The PurchaseOrderHeaderId (which is what I'm After) is defined as type Int and is set as identity (autoIncrement).

**EDIT:**

When this fails The following handler is highlighted with catch When(?) underlined with a red squiggle

public object TryCatchWhen(object source, Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    {
        object obj2 = null;
        try
        {
            obj2 = this.InternalRealCall(callback, args, numArgs);
        }
        catch when (?)
        {
            Exception exception;
            if (!this.CatchException(source, exception, catchHandler))
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return obj2;
    }

Further examination of the code created by Entity Framework data model showed that the function created to use the procedure returns a value of type Nullable of(Integer) so I changed retval to be of that type, but still I get the exception.

But I am still getting PurchaseOrderHeaders created by the stored procedure;

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the values passed to the `insert` rather than the `scope_identity()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff given that I am seeing several successfully created Purchase Order Headers (and that I have verified the validity of the input parameters prior to calling the procedure) I think the problem is on the return leg, just can't figure out what it might be though.

Comment: What do you get if you ToString the result before casting?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer  Great idea, hadn't thought of that so just tried it, unfortunately still the same problem.  Have added some extra info to the question and you can see that the sproc is successfully creating the headers, I'm just not getting the id.

Comment: Some other thoughts: Do this proc ever work? Do you have other similar procs that always work? Can you get the value of scope_identify into a var in the proc and return the var value?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer  yes this procedure works (see the edit in the original question above).  This is the only procedure in the entity model designed to bring back the identity , but there are literally dozens of others retuning scalar values to multiple recordsets all of which work flawlesslesy.  I haven't tried using an output variable possibly I may have to.

Comment: Appologies. I meant, does the call sometimes work and sometimes not work.

Comment: No Need to apologise,  the procedure always succeeds in creating a new header.